# Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long when running setup:upgrade

Tags: magento2, database, error, setup-upgrade

I get the following syntax error when running setup:upgrade after the update of a specific module through composer:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key
> was too long; max key length is 767 bytes, query was: CREATE TABLE
> `sendcloud_shipping_methods` ( `id` int(11)  NOT NULL  AUTO_INCREMENT
> COMMENT "Primary key", `store_view_id` int(11)  NOT NULL   COMMENT
> "Store view ID", `external_id` varchar(300) NOT NULL  COMMENT
> "External id", `delivery_zone_id` varchar(64) NOT NULL  COMMENT
> "Delivery zone id", `data` longtext NULL COMMENT "Shipping method
> data", `country` varchar(100) NOT NULL  COMMENT "Shipping method
> country", `internal_title` varchar(300) NOT NULL  COMMENT "Shipping
> method internal title", `external_title` varchar(300) NOT NULL
> COMMENT "Shipping method external title", `shipping_product`
> varchar(300) NOT NULL  COMMENT "Shipping method shipping product",
> `rates_enabled` tinyint(2)  NOT NULL   COMMENT "Shipping method rates
> enabled", `delivery_method` varchar(100) NOT NULL  COMMENT "Shipping
> delivery method", CONSTRAINT  PRIMARY KEY (`id`), CONSTRAINT
> `SENDCLOUD_SHIPPING_METHODS_EXTERNAL_ID` UNIQUE KEY (`external_id`),
> FULLTEXT INDEX
> `SENDCLOUD_SHIPPING_METHODS_EXTERNAL_TITLE_INTERNAL_TITLE`
> (`external_title`,`internal_title`) ) ENGINE=innodb DEFAULT
> CHARSET=utf8 DEFAULT COLLATE=utf8_general_ci COMMENT="SendCloud
> Shipping Methods"

The hosting support told me to upgrade MySQL to version 5.7 to solve this problem. Isn't there another solution to this problem? Upgrading the DB would take a lot of time where the MySQL version meets the Magento (2.3.5) requirements.

Magento 2.3.5

PHP 7.1

MySQL 5.6 (collation utf8_general_ci)

Comment: From a MySQL Command Prompt, what is result of SELECT @@version?  There will be more than 5.6 in your result.

Answer (score 0):

The limit for UTF8 is 767/3 = 255 characters, for UTF8m [see reference here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814532/mysql-error-1071-specified-key-was-too-long-max-key-length-is-767-bytes#:%7E:text=The%20limit%20for%20UTF8%20is,767%2F4%20%3D%20191%20characters.)

With this in mind, I'd ensure that these title fields are less that 255 together. How about changing from varchar(300) to varchar(100)?

one it would resolve your issue. More importantly, it is not great practice to have long fields in primary keys, it will only make your mysql server work harder..

Of course, do bear in mind, you may lose some data (your titles may get truncated). So, this solution is a shortcut for your upgrade to run. After, you may want to reimport your data using additional/custom fields.